# Is there a simple way to auto save property to Session/Cookies/Cache

Tags: asp.net, session, caching, cookies, viewstate

We are using asp.net and manytimes we found , we need write duplicate code to save some property to session or cookies or Cache:

Example such as :

```
public UserMaster CurrentUserMaster{
    get{
      return Session["CurrentUserMaster"] as UserMaster;
    }
    set {
      Session["CurrentUserMaster"] = value;
    }
}
public int ViewTimes{
    get{
      return (Int32)Cache["ViewTimes"];
    }
    set {
      Cache["ViewTimes"] = value;
    }
}
```

.....

If there a way to write there code like this ?

```
[Session("Session-Key-CurrentUserMaster")]
public UserMaster CurrentUserMaster{get;set;}

[Cache("Cache-Key-ViewTimes")]
public int ViewTimes{get;set;}
```

then auto save these properties to session , cache etc.

I found an article before and I want to implement for other container , thanks: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/54921/Automatic-ViewState-Properties-with-the-ViewState

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is site for answering questions, not writing code. Please show what you have tried and where you've run into an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer for this question: http://www.cnblogs.com/cyq1162/archive/2012/05/30/2526573.html